# Multiple commit in single pull request

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project in Github using fork repo. I am new to Github and I have to make a GitHub action YAML file so for debug I simply do commit on the GitHub and now when everything is working fine, I have to make a pull request to the main repo but now I have 130 commits in a single pull request. My question is how to make it one or some better way to do so?
WHat I have tried is to cherry-pick the last commit make a new branch and push it to first my remote repo, but it also contains 130 commits. [image]

Comment: One thing to work out is why it has 130 commits ahead of `RoboSherlock:noetic` if you're not expecting it?

Comment: basically Robosherlock: noetic is the main branch. these 130 commits come when I basically debug the action.YAML file, so I commit the change and try to find out if CI runs fine or not so that is why 130 commit came

Comment: If you do not want all those 130 commits and only want a couple, you can rebase and squash them together?

Comment: I tried the rebase command but it show "noop",

Comment: Well you need to talk more about that. What did you actually do? Did you use git blame? Are you still in the middle of it?

Comment: I first use `git rebase -i noetic` from the noetic-action branch and then I press enter with the `pick <last commit SHA>`  and status shows that it is rebaseing so I then quit the rebase. After I tried it again but now from the noetic branch then it showed me this "noop"

Comment: Should I take the first commit and update the files which I already did in a new branch and then commit it from this new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rebase` is showing noop since you're not specifying the starting commit of where you want to rebase from. You can do the following from command line.

Checkout to your `noetic` branch. Run the following command.

`git rebase -i HEAD~130`

In the interactive window, leave the first commit as `pick` and change the next 129 commits to `squash`. I have Vim as my default editor so I can run the following to easily squash the 129 unneeded commits:

`:s/pick/squash/ 129`

Once you're done, save & exit with: `:wq`

Do `:wq` again when the editor asks you to write your commit message (or edit the commit message as you like)

After this your rebase should be complete and you should have only one commit with all your changes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Just have one confusion the last commit in rebase shows the latest commit 6 hours ago while the first commit was a month ago, so should I pick the last commit and squash all others?

Comment: The changes are shown in reverse order in the rebase command. You can read more about it in the git reference. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

When you run the `git rebase -i` command, you will see this description in the bottom of the prompt:
`# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit`

So this means that the rebase command is actually melding all of your 130 commits into the oldest commit that you are rebasing into (in this case, 130 commits previous to `HEAD`).

Comment: If you want a more recent commit timestamp, you can always do a `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, then do a new `git commit` to set the timestamp to your current time.